# SQL Server Aggregation Using Partitioning

Tags: sql-server

I have been trouble writing a SQL query to roll up multiple balances based on a similar ID group and display the balance against products with a flag of N. I imagine I need to use a partition function or a max funcction to do this.

The desired results are in the table below underneath the sample dataset. Would anyone have a fix for this available?

Would anyone know logic to help for this? Basically I need to group everything by the ID and where there is a flag of N roll the balances up to that record, if there is no record with a flag of N we just aggregate by pdct_Type_C.

**SELECT** 
Client,
SUM(Limit) Limit,
SUM(Balance) Balance,
SUM(Exposure) Exposure,
MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'N' THEN Pdct_type_c ELSE NULL END) Pdct_type_c,
ID
**FROM** Table
**GROUP BY** Client, ID

**SAMPLE DATASET**

```
Client | Limit        | Balance        | Exposure | Pdct_type_c |  Flag | ID 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John   | 60,000,000.00| -              | 5,000,000| DERIV       |  N    | 2
John   | -            | 1,000,000.00   | -        | FX          |  y    | 2
John   | -            | 2,000,000.00   | -        | IC          |  y    | 2 
John   | 1,000,000.00 | 3,000,000.00   | -        | DCO         |  y    | 3
John   | 1,000,000.00 | 3,000,000.00   | -        | DCO         |  y    | 3
```

**CURRENT RESULTS**

```
Client | Limit        | Balance        | Exposure | Pdct_type_c |  Flag | ID 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John   | 60,000,000.00| 3,000,000.00   | 5,000,000| DERIV       |  N    | 2
John   | 2,000,000.00 | 6,000,000.00   | -        | NULL        |  Y    | 3
```

**DESIRED RESULTS**

```
Client | Limit        | Balance        | Exposure | Pdct_type_c |  Flag | ID 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John   | 60,000,000.00| 3,000,000.00   | 5,000,000| DERIV       |  N    | 2
John   | 2,000,000.00 | 6,000,000.00   | -        | DCO         |  Y    | 3
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried. At the most basic (assuming your sample is representative of all data) you need to use `GROUP BY` and it is a fairly simple query. Also you should not post data as pictures. Include it in the actual question as text. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thankyou, I have posted a basic dataset with the results I am seeking. Basically I am looking to aggregate groups based on the same ID and roll the balances up into the client in that group with a flag = 'N' .

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that this is doable with a windowing function. However here is the old fashioned way of doing it

This shows us just the records that have an N entry

```
SELECT
ID, 
MIN(Pdct_type_c) Pdct_type_c 
FROM Table
WHERE Flag = 'N'
GROUP BY ID
```

This outer joins to it to decide what to group on

```
SELECT 
T.Client,
SUM(T.Limit) Limit,
SUM(T.Balance) Balance,
SUM(T.Exposure) Exposure,
ISNULL(N.Pdct_type_c, T.Pdct_type_c) Pdct_type_c
CASE WHEN N.Pdct_type_c IS NULL THEN T.Flag ELSE 'N' END Flag,
T.ID
FROM Table T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
ID, 
MIN(Pdct_type_c) Pdct_type_c 
FROM Table
WHERE Flag = 'N'
GROUP BY ID
) N
ON T.ID = N.ID
GROUP BY T.Client, T.ID,
ISNULL(N.Pdct_type_c, T.Pdct_type_c),
CASE WHEN N.Pdct_type_c IS NULL THEN T.Flag ELSE 'N' END
```

Comment: That's another issue I am having, when there is no flag of 'N', as in case above, I would want the other products to remain as they are or if they have the same pdct_type_c then to aggregate into one record. 

Client is just a normal varchar type name so could be 'Ron' or 'Greg' , The ID field shows that the records are all part of the same transaction, so in case above clients would have a credit limit of $60,000,000 and have drawn down $3,000,000 of that limit, using separate products (FX and IC). My aim is to have that $3,000,000 aggregate against the DERIV product.

Comment: The best thing to do is edit your question and extend your data example. From what I understand from your comment, its mostly about getting the case statement correct to pick out the correct pdct_type_c

Comment: Thankyou, I will do this going forward